# number range in comma separated string

Tags: java, numbers, range

I have to create a method that allow user to create offer id range like follows ...

3,4,5 
  3,*,6
  3,102,*
  3,104,*

in the above examples there are three type of format (i.e x,x,x OR x,*,x OR x,x,*), where   x is a number in asc order.

my problem is in i have to make sure that user is not able to create offer id range with overlap id range. for example ...

if offer id   3,102,* already created than user not able to create following combinations ...   3,102,105 similarly if offer id range 3,* is already exists than user not able to create 3,4 Or 3,5 OR 3,10,11 like combinations.

i am not able to complete my following method

```
String[] digits1 = range1.split(",");
            String[] digits2 = range2.split(",");
            int digits1Len = digits1.length;
            int digits2Len = digits2.length;

            if (digits1[digits1Len -1].equals("*")) {
                --digits1Len; 
            }
            if (digits2[digits2Len -1].equals("*")) {
                --digits2Len; 
            }

            String[] digits1_1 = new String[digits1Len];
            String[] digits2_2 = new String[digits2Len];;
            System.arraycopy(digits1, 0, digits1_1, 0, digits1Len);
            System.arraycopy(digits2, 0, digits2_2, 0, digits2Len);

            if(!Arrays.asList(digits1_1).contains("*") || !Arrays.asList(digits2_2).contains("*")) {
                if (digits1_1[digits1Len -1].equals(digits2_2[digits2Len -1])) {                        
                    if(digits1Len != digits2Len) {
                        result = false;
                    } else{
                        // Loop                         
                    }
                } else if(false/*Lenght of the array with higher element should be more by 1 as compared to ther array*/) {

                }   
            } else {
                String [] normalPatternArr = null;
                String [] oldPatternArr = null;
                if(Arrays.asList(digits1_1).contains("*")) {
                    if (digits1_1.length < digits2_2.length) {
                        result = false;
                    } else {
                        normalPatternArr = digits2_2;
                        oldPatternArr = digits1_1;
                    }
                } else if(Arrays.asList(digits2_2).contains("*")) {
                    if (digits2_2.length < digits1_1.length) {
                        result = false;
                    } else {
                        normalPatternArr = digits1_1;
                        oldPatternArr = digits2_2;
                    }
                } else {                        
                    for (int i=0; i < normalPatternArr.length; i++) {
                        if (!normalPatternArr[i].equals(oldPatternArr[i])) {
                            if (!oldPatternArr[i].equals("*")) {
                                result = false;                                 
                                return result;
                            } else {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }                   
            }
```

Comment: what a huge monolithic mess of a method.  Try splitting it up into logical methods (which only do one thing)

Comment: Sorry for your trouble.I reduced the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think an easier way is to keep it as a String

E.g.

```
String orig = "3,4,5,*";
```

becomes

```
String mask = "3,4,5,";

if (secondString.startsWith (mask)) 
    // say no
```

but there again, maybe you are not explaining your problem correctly

Answer (score 0):

This class stores one triple of these ids:

```
public class IdRange {
private Integer[] triple = new Integer[3];
public IdRange(Integer a, Integer b, Integer c ){
    this.triple[0] = a;
    this.triple[1] = b;
    this.triple[2] = c;
}
public Integer getTriple( int i ){ return triple[i]; }
public boolean overlap( IdRange other ){
for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
    if( this.triple[i] == null ||
            other.getTriple( i ) == null ) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public String toString(){
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if( triple[0] == null ) sb.append( '*' );
    else sb.append( triple[0] );
    sb.append( ',' ); 
    if( triple[1] == null ) sb.append( '*' );
    else sb.append( triple[1] );
    sb.append( ',' ); 
    if( triple[2] == null ) sb.append( '*' );
    else sb.append( triple[2] );
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

This class parses a string containing a triple with missing or asterisked values and checks for overlaps:

```
public class Ranges {
private List<IdRange> rangeList = new ArrayList<>();
public boolean parseAndCheck( String s ){
String[] abc = s.split( "," );
    Integer a = null;
    Integer b = null;
    Integer c = null;
    if( abc.length == 3 &&
        ! "*".equals( abc[2] ) &&
        ! "".equals( abc[2] ) ){
        c = Integer.valueOf( abc[2] );
    }
    if( abc.length >= 2 &&
        ! "*".equals( abc[1] ) &&
        ! "".equals( abc[1] ) ){
        b = Integer.valueOf( abc[1] );
    }
    if( abc.length >= 1 &&
        ! "*".equals( abc[0] ) &&
        ! "".equals( abc[0] ) ){
        a = Integer.valueOf( abc[0] );
    }

    IdRange nrng = new IdRange( a, b, c );
    for( IdRange r: rangeList ){
        if( r.overlap( nrng ) ) return true;
    }
    rangeList.add( nrng );
    return false;
}

public void dump(){
    for( IdRange r: rangeList ){
        System.out.println( r );
    }
}

public static void main( String[] args ){
    Ranges ranges = new Ranges();
    for( String s: args ){
        if( ranges.parseAndCheck( s ) ){
            System.out.println( "overlap: " + s );
        }
    }
    ranges.dump();
}
}
```